# how to vertically align table data

Tags: html, css

i have the following table where the alignment goes wrong because some of the values have brackets in them.  I build the data in C# although the table is rendered using html.  I do have jquery available.  Is there a way to correct the alignment in either of these languages please?

```
| VALUE  |
| 40%    |
| 20%    |
| (30%)  |
| 10%    |
```

Notice how the 30% is not aligned correct because of the brackets.

Thanks,
James

Comment: Post some code. Are you using asp.net mvc?

Comment: I can post the code but it will have to wait until tomorrow..

Comment: is this something that C# can handle elegantly or jquery?  I'm thinking something more robust then just checking if the brackets exist and then using the no breaking space or something..

Comment: If you mean to move the 40%, 20% and so on over slightly, that's horizontal alignment. ;)

Comment: It's seems like this is neither a jquery question nor a C# one. It's an html/css question.

Comment: Is the data dynamic or static?

Comment: You could use a fixed width font and add spaces if there are no brackets

Comment: Do you want to align the '%' character of the each cell, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/B64eJ/3/? In HTML 4, there was the `char` attribute that was meant to do this, but it seems that no browser has ever supported it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are building the data on server-side (C#), (and that being numbers they would be better off right-aligned) you could append a space before sending the data down to client.

(1) Convert data to string. If brackets are because of being negative then just append a space to positive numbers while converting to string. If brackets are there after conversion to string (result of format), then append space to string values not ending with a ")".

For example: while formatting the numbers:

```
string myFormat = "#0% ;(#0%)";
myValue.ToString(myFormat);
```

Notice the space after the positive part (first part) of the format.

For example: if data is already string:

```
if (! stringValue.Substring(stringValue.Length - 1) == ")") {
    stringValue += " ";
}
```

Now you have a space padding on your data for positive numbers (or non-bracketed strings).

(2) Once this data is brought to the client, you specify *css* `text-align:right` to the table cells. However, if your font is proportionate then this will not line up. So specify a *monospace* font for these cells (or column). e.g. `font-family: courier new`; I have also found out that `font-family: verdana`; will also line up numbers properly as if *monospaced*.

Answer (score 1):

You can correct that using `css`

```
table tr td{
    text-align:center;
}
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B64eJ/)

If you want to make them left align and yet make the non brackets number to indent slightly you can use `text-indent` property

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B64eJ/2/)

Comment: This is definitely one option! It's not the same as keeping things left-aligned but the bracketless numbers indented, but still one way to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions I can think of:

1) Always add the brackets, just make them the same color as the background if you don't need them (you can do that by wrapping the actual value in a `<span>`). This will not work if someone uses copy&paste on the table.

2) Add spaces instead of the brackets when they aren't there and style the table with a fixed width font and preserved whitespace.

```
td {
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GeraldS/SqB3X/

Both solutions are not really pretty, I guess I'd go with Khawer's second example, but this will only work if the visitor doesn't change the font size in his browser.